# Sort List<Object> via Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I got two types like:

```
class Person 
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Car {get;set;}
}
```

and second type:

```
class Employee
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Salary {get;set;}
}
```

where **property's** *Name* is same(on both types).
Also I got Lists:

```
List<Person> _ListPerson = new List<Person>
List<Employee> _ListEmployee = new List<Employee>();
```

Where I added some items:

```
_ListPerson.Add( new Person { Name = "Jora" , Car = "BMW" };
_ListPerson.Add( new Person { Name = "Andrew" , Car = "Audi" };
_ListPerson.Add( new Person { Name = "Vasya" , Car = "Jiguli" };
_ListPerson.Add( new Person { Name = "Vasya" , Car = "Mercedes" };
_ListPerson.Add( new Person { Name = "Andy" , Car = "Renault" };  

_ListEmployee.Add(new Employee { Name = "Vasya", Salary = "1000$"};
_ListEmployee.Add(new Employee { Name = "Andy", Salary = "200$"};
_ListEmployee.Add(new Employee { Name = "Andrew", Salary = "5000$"};
_ListEmployee.Add(new Employee { Name = "Jora", Salary = "100$"};
```

For some reason I need to unite this types:

```
List<Object> People = New List<Object>();  
People.AddRange(_ListPerson);
People.AddRange(_ListEmployee);
```

So how I can **sort** this guys via lambda expressions?
At current I'm doing something like this:

```
var _TEMP = _List.OfType<Person>().GroupBy(x => x.Name);....  //etc ,how i can use order by for these two types? Because oftype works only for one type.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is for `Person` and `Employee` to share some common base class or implement a common interface.  For example:

```
public interface IName
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class Person : IName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
}

class Employee : IName
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Salary { get; set;}
}
```

And then instead of creating a `List<object>` and using `OfType`, you could create your list using this common type:

```
var people = new List<IName>();  
people.AddRange(_ListPerson);
people.AddRange(_ListEmployee);
```

And group:

```
var grouped = people.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
```

Though you mention you want to sort, which would actually be achieved using `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`:

```
var sorted = people.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: There is even a chance that `Employee`s are `Person`s (the ones I know are). In that case `Person` is the *common* base class.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden In this case the modelling implies that Employee's don't have cars.  Your point is a good one - I might have shown technically how this can be achieved, but it would be a good idea to check your abstractions make sense.

Comment: @CharlesMager Yes, that is what I was getting at. The names of the `Employee`s and `Person`s in the example data are the same, further indicating they might reference the same object. The technical problem here may very well be a consequence of a problem in the model.

Answer (score 1):

The *right* way to do this is either have a common interface (as per Charles') answer or a common base class (as Peter suggested in the comments on Charles' answer).

Since an employee, most likely, *is a* `Person`, I think it makes more sense to me to have `Employee` derive from `Person`. So:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Salary { get; set;}
}
```

The `IName` interface seems a little unnatural otherwise. Of course, this isn't the only way to model it. You could also say that a `Person` *has a* job:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public string Salary { get; set;}
    public Person Employee { get; set; }    
}
```

However, if you are absolutely stuck and are unable to change the `Person` and `Employee` class (perhaps it comes from some third-party source), you *could* do something like this:

```
var temp = People.Cast<dynamic>().OrderBy(a => a.Name);
```

Which casts your list to `dynamic` so that the check for the `Name` property will only happen at run-time and not compile-time. Note, however, if you stick something in your `People` list that doesn't have a `Name` property, then you will get a run-time error.

Another alternative is to just do something like this:

```
    var tenp = People.OrderBy(a => {
        string t = null;
        if (a is Person) {
            t = ((Person)a).Name;
        }
        else if (a is Employee) {
            t = ((Employee)a).Name;
        }
        return t;
    });
```

Which is considerable more verbose, but doesn't require `dynamic`. However, in this case, since I didn't add an `else` clause, anything that isn't a `Person` or an `Employee` will be sorted on `null` which might not be the desired behavior.

Hopefully the drawbacks of these work-arounds will convince most people that it's better to properly design your class hierarchy to avoid this problem. Even if you are stuck with the classes you are given, it might, depending on the exact usage, be worth translating them into a more sensible hierarchy and then working with that.